# Unable to open a site using urrlib in python

Tags: python, scala

I have a rest api server running at `localhost:8080`

Basically I am running an example from this site : https://github.com/spray/spray-template/tree/on_spray-can_1.1/src/main/scala/com/example

On my localhost:8080 I see the

> "Say hello to spray-routing on spray-can!"

message..

Now my python code is :

```
import urllib
proxies = {'http': 'http://proxy.abcd.com:800'}
response = urllib.urlopen("http://localhost:8080",proxies=proxies)
print response.read()
```

This is what I see:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">

</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
```

So, I am working behind proxy..I have specified the proxy but its still not working.
Any clues

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`localhost:8080` is only accessible from your PC. Not from elsewhere. So when you use a proxy like this `proxy.abcd.com:800`, from that proxy server, your `localhost` is unreachable. That's why it is not working for you. If you really need to test the code, the change the url into any other publicly visible sites like google, yahoo, example, etc.

```
response = urllib.urlopen("http://www.example.com",proxies=proxies)
```

Or, remove the proxy:

```
response = urllib.urlopen("http://localhost:8080")
```

Comment: @Sabuj.. Actually I am using the same machine (so local host should be accessible?)

Comment: Yes, it should find if they are on same pc/server. May be something wrong with your proxy? To make sure, please check if there is `127.0.0.1 localhost` exists in `/etc/hosts` file. Also, try changing the localhost into `www.mydomainxyz.com` from your code. And map like this `127.0.0.1 www.mydomainxyz.com` in `hosts` file.